# Creating a hash from two arrays with identical values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm having issues creating a hash from 2 arrays when values are identical in one of the arrays.
e.g.

```
names = ["test1", "test2"]
numbers = ["1", "2"]
Hash[names.zip(numbers)]
```

works perfectly it gives me exactly what I need `=> {"test1"=>"1", "test2"=>"2"}`

However if the values in "names" are identical then it doesn't work correctly

```
names = ["test1", "test1"]
numbers = ["1", "2"]
Hash[names.zip(numbers)]
```

shows `{"test1"=>"2"}` however I expect the result to be `{"test1"=>"1", "test1"=>"2"}`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Hashes can't have duplicate keys. Ever.

If they were permitted, how would you access "2"? If you write `myhash["test1"]`, which value would you expect?

Rather, if you expect to have several values under one key, make a hash of arrays.

```
names = ["test1", "test1", "test2"]
numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]

Hash.new.tap { |h| names.zip(numbers).each { |k, v| (h[k] ||= []) << v } }
# => {"test1"=>["1", "2"], "test2"=>["3"]}
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel embarrassed for missing that part.
All I wanted to do is iterate through the array.
Eventually did smth like this.
`names.zip(numbers).each_with_index do |(name, number), i|`

Comment: `keys.zip(values).each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h.update({k=>[v]}) { |_,ov,_| ov << v } }` is another way of doing the same thing.