# Merge arrays to hash and use duplicates

Tags: ruby, hash

How do I keep duplicates and maintain order? For example:

```
keys   = [1, 2, 1]
values = ["a", "b", "c"]
Hash[keys.zip(values)] # => {1=>"c", 2=>"b"}
```

Comment: Hashes don't support duplicate keys. The closest thing I could think of would be to have your value be an array.

Comment: @nithin think about it, what should `hash[1]` return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Justin & Luca said:

> Hashes don't allow duplicate keys.

Best you can do is by having array of values, found this solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583400/creating-a-hash-from-two-arrays-with-identical-values-in-ruby) SO question:

```
Hash.new.tap { |h| keys.zip(values).each { |k, v| (h[k] ||= []) << v } }
# => {1=>["a", "c"], 2=>["b"]}
```

Comment: Not sure why you call it a hack, but yes using Arrays with values is a good way to handle this scenario. +1

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers english isn't my first language, what's a better word?

Comment: A solution or so :-)

Comment: ..or `keys.zip(values).each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h.update({k=>[v]}) { |_,ov,_| ov << v } }`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot keep duplicates if you use the keys array as hash key. They must be unique