# Pluck doesn't return a bother records they have the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pluck

I have a pluck that is turned into a hash and stored in a variable

```
@keys_values_hash = Hash[CategoryItemValue.where(category_item_id: @category_item.id).pluck(:key, :value)]
```

If 2 records have the same `:key` name then only the most recent record is used and they aren't both added to the hash. But if they have the same `value` and different `keys` both are added to the hash.

This also occurs if I swap `:key` and `:value` around (`.pluck(:value, :key)`). If they have now the same `value` it only uses the most recent one and stores that in the hash. But having the same `key` is now fine.

I'm not sure of this is being caused by pluck or from being sorted in a hash. I'm leaning towards pluck being the culprit.

What is causing this and how can I stop it from happening. I don't want data being skipped if it has the same `key` name as another record.

Comment: pluck is no culprit. Hash can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25447081/2231236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need convert pluck result into a Hash, because it was an Array original.

Like you have three `CategoryItemValue` like below:

```
id,   key,   value
 1,    foo,   bar1
 2,    foo,   bar2
 3,    baz,   bar3
```

when you pluck them directly, you will get a array like:
`[ ['foo', 'bar1'],  ['foo', 'bar2'],  ['baz', 'bar3'] ]`

but when you convert it into a hash, you will get:
`{'foo' => 'bar2', 'baz' => 'bar3' }`

because new hash value will override the old one if key ( `foo` in the example above) exists.

Or you could try `Enumerable#group_by` method:
`CategoryItemValue.where(...).pluck(:key, :value).group_by { |arr| arr[0] }`

Comment: I'm using the template engine [liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) which requires the information be in a hash not an array unfortunately. Any way around this that keeps it in a hash?

Comment: @user3234020 It's able to convert a pluck result into hash by `Array.to_h`. But I don't think you can assign two variable to one variable in liquid template engine either. Think about when you get `[ %w(foo bar1), %w(foo bar2) ]`, how could liquid render `{{foo}}` variable? is `bar` or `bar2`?  So it also required a unique key.

Comment: I planned on having a method or statement that if 2 keys were the same to put the value of one into the other e.g. `{'foo' => 'bar2', 'foo' => 'bar3' }` becomes {'foo' => 'bar2, bar3' } which works for my application. I just realised I can do this to the array before it is converted into a hash. `[ ['foo', 'bar1'],  ['foo', 'bar2'], ['baz', 'bar3'] ]` into `[ ['foo', 'bar1, bar2'], ['baz', 'bar3']]` now to figure out how.